# Issue with data gap on time series data

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image: What the code allows me to plot]
[image: What I know USGS has available]
[image: What the code does when I try to plot the whole data set]
I'm having issues with data gaps in my time series code. I am pulling data from a USGS site and I want to plot data from 1986-2019 using seasonal averages. However, at this particular site, there is a data gap from 2006-2008 that is preventing this. The code will plot 2008-2019, but when it sees the data gap, it cannot handle it. I don't know if this is as simple as NA=TRUE somewhere or something more complex. I just want to ignore this gap. Thanks for your help!

Kelsey

```
library(waterData)

## List of start dates
start.dates <- c ( "1986-12-01", "1987-12-01", "1988-12-01",
                   "1989-12-01", "1990-12-01", "1991-12-01", "1992-12-01",
                   "1993-12-01", "1994-12-01", "1995-12-01", "1996-12-01",
                   "1997-12-01", "1998-12-01", "1999-12-01", "2000-12-01",
                   "2001-12-01", "2002-12-01", "2003-12-01", "2004-12-01",
                   "2005-12-01", "2006-12-01", "2007-12-01", "2008-12-01",
                   "2009-12-01", "2010-12-01", "2011-12-01", "2012-12-01",
                   "2013-12-01", "2014-12-01", "2015-12-01", "2016-12-01",
                   "2017-12-01", "2018-12-01")

## List of end dates

end.dates <- c(  "1987-05-31", "1988-05-30", "1989-05-31", 
                 "1990-05-31", "1991-05-31", "1992-05-30", "1993-05-31", 
                 "1994-05-31", "1995-05-31", "1996-05-30", "1997-05-31", 
                 "1998-05-31", "1999-05-31", "2000-05-30", "2001-05-31", 
                 "2002-05-31", "2003-05-31", "2004-05-30", "2005-05-31", 
                 "2006-05-31", "2007-05-31", "2008-05-30", "2009-05-31", 
                 "2010-05-31", "2011-05-31", "2012-05-30", "2013-05-31", 
                 "2014-05-31", "2015-05-31", "2016-05-30", "2017-05-31",
                 "2018-05-31", "2019-05-31")
 


## Bind start and end dates into a single dataframe
flow.dates <- as.data.frame(cbind(start.dates, end.dates))

## Empty dataframe for discharge data; nrow=no of days in each inverval, 
#ncol=no invtervals
discharge.data = as.data.frame(data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = 182, ncol = 33))) 

## Append data for all dates
for(x in 1:33){
  bin.1 <- importDVs(staid = "02196000", code = "00060", stat = "00003",
                     sdate = flow.dates[x, 1],
                     edate = flow.dates[x, 2])
  bin.2 <- cleanUp(bin.1, task = "fix", replace = 0.001)
  bin.3 <- fillMiss(bin.1, block = 2, pmiss = 5, model = "trend", 
                    smooth = FALSE, log = "y")
  bin.4 <- bin.3[, c(2, 3)]
  colnames(bin.4) <- c(flow.dates[x, 3])
  discharge.data[, x] <- bin.4[, 1]
}



## Calculate season mean & convert from ft3 to m3
mean.discharge.ws <- sapply(discharge.data, mean)
met.shift.ws <- (mean.discharge.ws / 35.315)

## Create dataframe

met.winterspring.Year <- c( 1987, 
                            1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996,
                            1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005,
                            2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014,
                            2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019)

df=data.frame(met.shift.ws, met.winterspring.Year)
my.formula = df$met.shift.ws ~ df$met.winterspring.Year

fit = lm(met.winterspring.Year ~  met.shift.ws ,data=df )
summary(fit)

library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc) # for dealing with stat equations
library (scales)

ggplot(df, aes(met.winterspring.Year, met.shift.ws)) +
  geom_line(group=1) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE) +
  stat_poly_eq(formula = my.formula,
               eq.with.lhs = "italic(hat(y))~`=`~",
               aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~")), 
               parse = TRUE)+
  theme_classic() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = breaks_width(2)) +
  labs(x="", y=(expression(Discharge~(m^{3}~s^{-1}))))+
  annotate(geom = "text", x = 2017, y =75, label = "Winter-Spring", hjust = "left")


  

      dput(df[sample(1:nrow(df), 33),])
structure(list(met.shift.ws = c(23.5738634860821, 19.1108749667436, 
9.29831671938426, 7.14075279970926, 4.01155689843216, 23.0833176451186, 
23.3716022049591, 4.97132712961681, 7.01824863512532, 7.67068129378762, 
11.5399396016697, 1.00388808416559, 4.77445533370778, 28.4664549665258, 
32.4367972392891, 10.595815058508, 15.7866485772475, 6.95898919146831, 
16.6857777646394, 6.97617828865174, 23.2273743529584, 5.15243499244632, 
14.9389715480612, 15.3223189100295, 17.9382418515931, 4.07121541915539, 
17.895891451038, 6.76626219596629, 10.9585473283619, 4.78861362338638, 
31.9130961067815, 20.7926152850406, 9.99793071150851), met.winterspring.Year = c(1987, 
2019, 2005, 2017, 2004, 2016, 1991, 2008, 2000, 2001, 1994, 2012, 
2011, 2003, 1998, 2015, 1989, 2013, 1990, 2018, 1995, 2006, 2009, 
2014, 1997, 2002, 2010, 1999, 2007, 1988, 1993, 1996, 1992)), row.names = c("X1", 
"X33", "X19", "X31", "X18", "X30", "X5", "X22", "X14", "X15", 
"X8", "X26", "X25", "X17", "X12", "X29", "X3", "X27", "X4", "X32", 
"X9", "X20", "X23", "X28", "X11", "X16", "X24", "X13", "X21", 
"X2", "X7", "X10", "X6"), class = "data.frame")   
     

 head(bin.1) 
     staid  val      dates qualcode
1 02196000  299 2018-12-01        A
2 02196000 4730 2018-12-02        A
3 02196000 1810 2018-12-03        A
4 02196000  554 2018-12-04        A
5 02196000  283 2018-12-05        A
6 02196000  187 2018-12-06        A
>   
>  head(discharge.data)
    X1 X2  X3 X4  X5  X6  X7  X8   X9 X10  X11  X12 X13 X14 X15  X16  X17 X18  X19
1 1480 14 181 93 114  33 395  82  711 145  529 1000  25  20  40 4.83 16.3  34 98.0
2 1780 22 136 88 103  36 329  62  374 135 1860  459  26  16  33 3.87 15.8  41 86.3
3 1220 25 111 85 101  43 277  53  276 125  694  270  26  13  30 3.00 14.7  40 90.8
4  583 19  97 82 112 168 238  48  274 120  298  206  26  12  26 2.53 14.6  73 81.2
5  342 17  88 80 144 239 223 134 2050 122  218  187  27  12  24 2.22 17.4 122 69.1
6  244 15  79 80 130 147 212 293  873 120  184  168  27  12  24 2.18 21.2  95 64.3
    X20  X21  X22    X23  X24  X25  X26  X27  X28  X29 X30  X31  X32  X33
1  17.8 41.0 6.58 1120.0  112 26.7 31.1 0.43 35.3 27.4 134 53.6 24.1  299
2  17.5 45.4 6.82  360.0  738 68.1 26.1 0.41 29.6 21.5 138 55.6 28.6 4730
3  18.0 44.1 9.69  149.0 5210 59.3 18.1 0.40 27.9 16.8 242 54.3 31.7 1810
4  18.5 35.6 8.90   83.8 1540 33.0 13.5 0.47 50.1 13.2 217 33.1 32.7  554
5  25.2 31.1 7.47   58.2  467 23.9 11.1 0.56 74.1 11.2 156 27.6 33.2  283
6 680.0 28.4 6.73   45.0  292 19.0 12.5 0.52 79.0 11.3 129 27.1 35.8  187
```

Comment: Hi OP.  Can you elaborate what happens when you try to run your code?  I'm unable to run/retrieve the data due to some of the packages you are using.  Is this a problem with `ggplot` not plotting correctly or is it an issue with the data preparation?  If possible, can you share `df` with us by posting `dput(df)`?  If that is too large (as it may be), at least filter the dataset of `df` to focus on just before and just after your gap to confirm the issue is there.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your comment. I added some images to help visualize the issue. The first image is what I am able to plot, the second is the data set that USGS has available and should be pulling from, and the third is what happens when I try to plot all of the available data. I believe this is an issue with the data gap, as the first plot coincides with the begining of the data gap. I'm just not sure how to handle this data gap and how to tell R just to ignore it. I believe its an issue with the data prep. Hope that helps

Comment: I'm having trouble downloading the data, but I believe that's due port 443 being blocked where I'm accessing.  Again, the best bet is to pull the data and share with us a sample of the dataset that spans the data between the "gap" of interest. It looks like you certainly have values in `df$met.winterspring.Year` that span your data (note your scale is "correct" on the x axis), but it's an issue with `df$met.shift.ws` not having sensible values.  This should not be due to having 'NA' in your dataset, as `ggplot2` can handle plotting those just fine.

Comment: Try plotting this dataset `df <- data.frame(x=c(1:250),y=c(rnorm(100), rep(NA,50), rnorm(100))` with this command `ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_line()` and you will see that the span without any data is handled fine.  This means it's all down to the structure of the dataset, which means you need to share some of `df`.  I would recommend to share the output of a sample of about 20-50 rows of `df`.  You can do that with: `dput(df[sample(1:nrow(df), 50),])`.  Copy and paste the output of that function in the body of your question (formatted as code,please).

Comment: Hi chemdork123, I've added dput output to the body of my question. I've never used that function before so I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for. You are right about the plot you added, it does work properly. Let me know what I can do to fix the structure. Thanks for your help

Comment: Yep - that's perfect.  I ran your `ggplot()` code and looks reasonably okay.  I left out the `stat_poly_eq()` function since `ggpmisc` is not available for the version of R I'm using.  However, you should still see the `geom_line` and `geom_smooth` plotted just fine in your example and you are not from the picture you shared.  ... not sure what's going on, but maybe you will need to update `ggplot2` and then run the plot code again without the extra `stat_poly_eq` call?  I would actually recommend to run on a fresh session where only `ggplot2` is loaded and see if you get a meaningful plot.

Comment: There is a discrepency in the number of rows between discharge.data and bin.1, which i think is causing the issue. The code works fine if I change " nrow=182" to "nrow=364" in the code. I've added the head(discharge.data) and head (bin.1) so you can see the structure of both. I think if the structure of discharge.data is changed that might fix the problem but i'm not sure how to do this.